# Multiple definitions of node winbugs

Tags: winbugs

I have some problem with this code in winbugs. The model is sintatically correct and data are loaded, but when I compile, software output is "multiple definitions of node Z". I don't know how to solve the problem.

This is the model:

```
#BUGS Model
model {
for (i in 1:n){
  for (j in 1:p){
    Y[i , j] ~ dcat ( prob [i , j , 1: M[j]])
    B <- sum(alpha[j])  
  } 
  theta [i] ~ dnorm (0.0 , 1.0)
}
for (i in 1:n){
  for (j in 1:p){
    for (k in 1:M[j]){
      Z <- sum(delta [k ])
      eta [i , j , k] <- 1.7* alpha [j] * (B * (theta [i] - beta [j] ) + Z)
      exp.eta[i , j , k] <- exp( eta[i , j , k])
      psum[ i , j , k] <- sum(eta[i , j , 1:k])
      prob[i , j , k] <- exp.eta[i , j , k] / psum[i , j , 1:M[j]]
    }
  }
}
for (j in 1:p){
  alpha [j] ~ dnorm (0 , pr.alpha) I(0 , )
  for (k in 2:M[j]){
    delta [k] ~ dnorm (0.0 , 1.0)
  }
  for (k in 1:M[j]){
    beta [j] ~ dnorm (0 , pr.beta )
  }
}
delta [1] <- 0.0
pr.alpha <- pow(1 , -2)
pr.beta <- pow(1, -2)
}

#data
list(n=10, p=8)

M[] M[] M[] M[] M[] M[] M[] M[]
2 2 4 2 2 3 4 2 
2 1 1 2 1 2 2 3
1 2 1 3 1 1 4 4
2 1 1 2 1 1 2 4 
3 4 4 3 3 3 1 1 
4 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 
1 1 2 2 1 2 4 4 
2 1 1 3 1 4 2 4 
3 4 1 1 1 2 2 2 
2 2 2 1 4 4 4 4 
END
```

Thanks to everyone that will answer.

Comment: @mima Can you provide all the data, or a sample to be able to make a reproducible example? When I try and compile, I get message that `M` is not defined

Comment: So is `M` a matrix or a vector? In the model you are using `M` as a vector (one long column of numbers), but in your comment it is a matrix?

Comment: this is the model for GPCM(Generalized partial credit model)in item response theory. that "i" is number of subject, "j" is number of item and "M[j]" is number of response category item j. so I have a i*j matrix.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Multiple definition of node a" error in Winbugs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14509546/multiple-definition-of-node-a-error-in-winbugs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problems lie in defining some nodes multiple times in BUGS loops. For example `B` is defined np times in the first `i` and `j` loop. BUGS will not allow this. You cannot override a node value. You need to either

1) Add some indexes to `B`, `Z`, `delta[k]` and `beta[j]` to enable BUGS to store simulated values within elements of nodes during the loops. e.g replace `B` with `B[i,j]` and `Z` with `Z[i,j,k]`

or

2) Move `B`, `Z`, `delta[k]` and `beta[j]` to loops that only cover the indexes they already have. i.e. `B`, `Z` not in a loop as they have no index, `delta[k]` only in a `for(k in 1:...)` loop.

The decision depends on what you have in mind for your model and what you want parameters you want to store.

Comment: B and Z is a constant and I can't add index to them. in above model I put B in for(j in 1:...) loop and I haven't problem with it. but z should be in 2 loop : for(j in 1:...) and for(k in 1:...). and it make problem.

Comment: thank you for your answer. If you want I can emailed the formula for this model. I'm really confounded.

Comment: `B` will be a problem, as will `delta` and `beta`, WinBUGS only tells you one error message at a time.

Comment: @mina so from your comment it sounds like `B` and `Z` are single constants and so need to be outside the loops.

Comment: if they were outside the loop, this error shows: "expected variable name". it's because of index for delta and beta.

Comment: if I change partof model to this:
`model{
for (i in 1:n){
for (j in 1:p){
Y[i,j] ~ dcat ( prob[i, j , 1: M[j]])  
} 
theta[i] ~ dnorm (0.0 , 1.0)
}
delta[1] <- 0.0
for (i in 1:n){
for (j in 1:p){
for (k in 1:M[j]){
B[j]<-sum(alpha[1:p])     
Z[j]<-sum(delta[1:k])
eta [i,j,k] <- 1.7*alpha[j]*(B[j]*(theta[i]-beta[j])+Z[j])
exp.eta[i,j,k]<- exp(eta[i,j,k])
psum[ i , j , k] <- sum(eta[i , j , 1:k])
prob[i , j , k] <- exp.eta[i , j , k] / psum[i , j , 1:M[j]]
}
}
}`
this error shows: "multiple definitions of node Z[1]"

Comment: @mina see my answer, `Z` would need to have all indexes for the loops that it sits within, otherwise you are overwriting (not allowed by BUGS)

Comment: @mina. You probably should undo your question edit, and create a new question for the update.... otherwise others that have the same (original) problem and find this question in the future will be lost.